# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to use a Hive Context but I get the following error:

```
exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext
```

Any suggestions?

```
package com.mapr.examples;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SparkSQLHiveContextExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkSQLHiveContextExample");
        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        // SQLContext sqlContext = new HiveContext(ctx); // exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext
        // HiveContext hiveContext = new HiveContext(ctx.sc()); // exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext
        // HiveContext hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(ctx.sc()); // exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext


        ctx.stop();
        ctx.close();

    }
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mapr.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkSQLExample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Do you understand what `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` means?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try after adding this dependency ?

It should work.

[maven link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-hivecontext-compatibility_2.10/2.0.0-preview)

Comment: I've added this as a jar file. I didn't get the same error. BUT... It's seems that HiveContext is no longer active. Apache Spark says it's deprecated. If you view your code on IDE, you'll notice the deprecated warning.   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spa rk/sql/hive/HiveContext.html

Comment: what do you mean `as a jar file`? to the dependencies `pom.xml` ?

Comment: thanks, do you have any idea what should I use instead, I just try to test if the hadoop cluster with hive is working, I am not java expert.

Comment: Maven is a build automation tool. When you trigger the action called maven install, you just simply download the related jars that you mentioned in pom.xml from maven repository. With maven, you're just adding jars to your build path , but in more flexible way :) And since I don't have a maven project on my local; downloading the related jar file from maven repo and adding it to my build path seems faster, so I did it :)

Comment: I don't have an Apache Spark experience. So, no I don't have a proper recommendation.

Comment: I didn't say something like mvn clean install would solve your problem. What I'm just trying to say is : you're not having the same error. Now you have an issue because HiveContext is deprecated.

Comment: Please make your answer selfstanding.  Links may go away without warning.  Think that your answer should be useful to others even when printed out on paper.

Comment: She was not even aware of the reason of the error. And no one answered the question because of the reason you've mentioned. I did my best to help her. What would you expect from me to do ? Should I not be warning her just because of I could not solve the whole error solely ? Sorry, but this perspective is so lame. Our main aim should be helping and rotating each other.